# Assinatura digital com C# e JSon

Tags: c#, json, certificado-digital

Boa tarde a todos.
Estou utilizando o código do link https://github.com/Gread/BoletoOnlineBradesco que utiliza o C# para assinar o JSon e enviar os boletos para o Bradesco.
Meu problema está ocorrendo na classe do Bouncy Castle (http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html), onde não consigo recuperar a chave privada.

```
private void AssinarCriptografar(EnvioRemessaCobrancaBradescoJson model)
    {
        try
        {

            //exemplo validacao
            var validador = new ValidarModelo();
            var criticas = validador.Criticas(model);
            if (criticas.Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            var data = ConverterParaJsonAspasSimples(model);
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            var messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);                

            var impressaDigitalCertificado = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpressaoDigitalCertificado"];

            // certificado precisa ser instalado na máquina local e na pasta pessoal, diferente disso alterar linha abaixo
            var store = new X509Store("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var privateCert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(cert => cert.Thumbprint == impressaDigitalCertificado && cert.HasPrivateKey);

            if (privateCert == null)                                    
                throw new Exception("Certificado não localizado.");                
            if (privateCert.PrivateKey == null)                
                throw new Exception("chave privada não localizada no certificado.");

            //convertendo certificado para objeto que o bouncycastle conhece
            var bouncyCastleKey = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(privateCert.PrivateKey).Private;
            var x5091 = new X509Certificate(privateCert.RawData);
            var x509CertBouncyCastle = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x5091);

            var generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
            var signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder();
            generator.AddSignerInfoGenerator(
                signerInfoGeneratorBuilder.Build(new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA256WithRSA", bouncyCastleKey),
                    x509CertBouncyCastle));

            //criando certstore que o bouncycastle conhece
            IList certList = new ArrayList();
            certList.Add(x509CertBouncyCastle);
            var store509BouncyCastle = X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", new X509CollectionStoreParameters(certList));
            generator.AddCertificates(store509BouncyCastle);

            var cmsdata = new CmsProcessableByteArray(messageBytes);
            //assina
            var signeddata = generator.Generate(cmsdata, true);
            var mensagemFinal = signeddata.GetEncoded();                
            //converte para base64 que eh o formato que o serviço espera
            var mensagemConvertidaparaBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(mensagemFinal);                

            //chama serviço convertendo a string na base64 em bytes
            CriarServicoWebEEnviar("url_servico_bradesco_consta_manual", encoding.GetBytes(mensagemConvertidaparaBase64));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Quando aciono a função abaixo me retorna o erro "{"Chave inválida para uso no estado especificado.\r\n"}".
var bouncyCastleKey = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(privateCert.PrivateKey).Private;

Verificando o código da Bouncy Castle, o erro ocorre quando o mesmo tenta enviar seus parametros para a classe GetRsaKeyPair((RSA)privateKey) e depois GetRsaKeyPair(rsa.ExportParameters(true))

```
public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GetKeyPair(AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
    {
        if (privateKey is DSA)
        {
            return GetDsaKeyPair((DSA)privateKey);
        }

        if (privateKey is RSA)
        {
            return GetRsaKeyPair((RSA)privateKey);
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported algorithm specified", "privateKey");
    }

public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair GetRsaKeyPair(
        RSA rsa)
    {
        return GetRsaKeyPair(rsa.ExportParameters(true));
    }
```

Quando tenta passar o parametro rsa.ExportParameters como verdadeiro, ocorre o erro, pois como falso ele continua o processo, porém ocorre outros erros em cadeia posteriormente por causa da falta de parâmetros.

**Estou usando o Visual Studio 2010 com o .NET Framework 4.0.0**

Já estou a duas semanas nesse caso e preciso entender o que está ocorrendo.
Agradeço desde já a contribuição de todos.

Comment: Se você esta utilizando um certificado digital do tipo "A1", você precisa configura-lo durante a instalação dizendo que irá guardar as informações da chave privada, caso contrario provavelmente irá ocorrer este erro. Por padrão o A1 não faz isso que falei...